# Relation of $\det(M(x)\delta(x-y))$ to $\det(M(x))$?

Tags: functional-analysis, determinant

The two functional determinants $\det(M(x)\delta(x-y))$ to $\det(M(x))$ often appear in path integration (aka functional integration). From the form in which they appear in these integrals it is apparent that:
$$ \det(M(x)\delta(x-y))\propto \det(M(x))$$
is it possible to show this? And does it only hold when the determinants are evaluated on certain special spaces or does it hold more generally?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a standard matrix $M_{ij}$ the determinant of this matrix is given by: 
$$\det(M_{ij})=\prod_k \lambda_K \tag{1}$$
where $\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues of $M_{ij}$ defined by:
$$M_{ij}v_j^{(k)}=\lambda_k v^{(k)}_i$$
for the continuous 'matrix' of the form $M(x,y)$ the analogous to the above equation is:
$$\int dy M(x,y) f_k(y)=\lambda_kf_k(x)$$
($k$ here and in the above labels eigenvectors). Thus for $M(x,y)=M(x) \delta(x-y)$ we get:
$$\int dy M(x) \delta(x-y)f_k(y)=\lambda_kf_k(x)$$
$$M(x)f_k(x)=\lambda_kf_k(x)\tag{2}$$
(2) is thus the eigenvalue equation solved when finding the determinate of $M(x,y)$. It is also that solved when finding $\det(M(x))$ which I now realize is a slight abuse of notation. Thus we have that:
$$\det(M(x)\delta(x-y))= \det(M(x))$$
which holds generally. I am even tempted to write that:
$$\det(M(x)\delta(x-y))\equiv \det(M(x))$$
since $M(x)$ is not really a 'matrix' acting on its own.

Comment: It seems $M(x)$ is not a matrix? What does $\det M(x)$ mean?

Comment: @CalvinKhor In the past I have taken $\det(M(x))$ to mean simply the product of the eigenvalues in the eigenvalue equation: $$M(x)f(x)=\lambda f(x)$$ ($M(x)$ here is an operator on functions)

Comment: Well the 'determinant' is infinite for many operators. Take 2 times the identity on any infinite dimensional space.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I know, like I said in the question these often appear in path (/functional) integrals  which are ill defined mathematically anyway.

Comment: Well I don't think they are necessarily ill defined, but I don't know enough to tell you why. As far as I'm aware there isn't a useful generalisation of determinant but there is a useful generalisation of eigenvalue (spectrum) which might get you on the 'path to rigour'. Maybe you even know this. Have a good day, thanks for responding